# How to catch error without using Validator class in Laravel

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, validation

When I use Validator class in Laravel I am able to catch errors like this for my ajax-

```
$validator= Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'age' => 'required|min:3',
            'number' => 'required|numeric',
        ]);
        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json([
                'status'=> 400,
                'errors'=>$validator->messages(),
            ]);
        }
```

But how can I catch the error messages without using Validator class or using this code-

```
$request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'age' => 'required|min:3',
            'number' => 'required|numeric',
        ]);
```

I want to store error messages in a variable in Controller so I can send them to JSON

Comment: catch the exception that is thrown by `validate`

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php

```php
try {
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'age' => 'required|min:3',
        'number' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);
} catch (ValidationException $e) {
    if($request->wantsJson()) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 400,
            'errors' => $e->errors(),
        ]);
    }
    
    throw $e; // return to laravel default handler 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With the $errors var in the blade view [Display Errors](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

Comment: I want to store error messages in a variable in Controller so I can send them to JSON.

Comment: If your request is in ajax, try to get the 422 status code in fail,
this response(422) have the errors in json format